# How to disable border-radius of bootstrap inputs in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap input controls and trying to disable the border by setting it to 0px, but its not working.

I have seen a lot of posts here but none of them worked for me. I tried to use `!important` and moved the css classes to the main `style.css` file and again its not working.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="manager" required #manager #manager (change)="selectedValueManager(manager.value)">
      <option value="">choose manager</option>
      <option *ngFor="let manager of this.flowManagers" value={{manager.id}}> {{manager.name}}</option>
   </select>
   <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.form-group {
   border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the class `rounded-0` to the input

Comment: Then it means you have other class that conflicts, use chrome inspector to check the element

Comment: ok its work it but I still see  radios on the border :/ in dev tools the border radios is 0 but it still not square

Comment: Ok its work now maybe was a conflicts as you mention

Answer (score 1):

You should apply that rule on the `.form-control` css class, and also make sure you load first the `boostrap.css` and after that your `styles.css`

```
.form-control {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I check what load first??

Comment: It depends on that, where you are importing the `bootstrap.css` (`angular.json`, `styles.css` or `index.html`)

Answer (score 0):

Do like below. Apply style to `.form-control` class

```
.form-control {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it more specific than bootstrap:

```
    select.from-control {
          border-radius:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this properties to remove border
`border-color: transparent;`